# Loading sound effects into an array

Tags: javascript

I'm loading my game's sound effects into an array to easily pick a random one and play it. Previously, I used a switch statement to select a random sound but it looks less verbose to just pick an array key.

Is it inefficient to use an array to store and play my sound effects? Is there a better way to do this or any improvements I can make to my implementation?

```
let sounds = [];

function loadSounds() {
  const sources = ['sound1.ogg', 'sound2.ogg', 'sound3.ogg', 'sound4.ogg', 'sound5.ogg', 'sound6.ogg'];
    
  for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
      sounds[i] = new Audio(sources[i]);
  }
}

function playRandomSound() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    
    sounds[randomNumber].play();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is perfectly fine, it's what I'd prefer as well. But there are some improvements you can make:

- When you have an array and you want to create a new array by transforming every item of an old array, it's most appropriate to use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

  ```
  // I'd call it `filenames` and `audios`, not `sources` and `sounds`;
  // `audios` is plural of Audio and is a bit more precise
  const audios = filenames.map(filename => new Audio(filename));
  ```
- If your sound files are really numeric-indexed, it would be even easier to just iterate over the *numbers* 1 to 4, rather than having to list `sound1.ogg`, `sound2.ogg`, etc.
- [Always declare variables with `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) when possible - only use `let` when you must reassign the variable name. Using `const` makes code easier to read, when a reader can determine that the variable name won't ever be reassigned at a glance.
- At the moment, if `playRandomSound` is called multiple times in a row, multiple sounds may be active at once, which may sound very discordant and not be desirable. In such a case, you may wish to save the `randomNumber` in a persistent outer variable so that you can call `.stop()` on the prior `Audio` before `.play()`ing another. (Or, if you want to have playing sounds overlap, your current approach is just fine)
- If your `sources` array's length changes, you'll also need to change this section: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);` Better to put the array's length there instead of the 6.

```
const audios = Array.from(
  { length: 6 },
  (_, i) => new Audio(`sound${i + 1}.ogg`)
);
function playRandomSound() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * audios.length);
    sounds[randomNumber].play();
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I didn't realize I could have assigned `sounds` as const in my original example because I assumed constants never change. I learnt a lot, thank you :)